# Undefined packages added after "npm update -g"

Tags: npm

I accidentally installed "react" and "react-dom" as global packages, and promptly uninstalled them.

But now everytime I run `npm update -g`, two undefined packages "+ undefined@0.1.0 (as react-dom)" and "+ undefined@0.1.0 (as react)" are added. `npm list -g --depth 0` lists them as "+-- react@npm:undefined@0.1.0" and "+-- react-dom@npm:undefined@0.1.0".

They are not breaking anything, and I can always just uninstall them after they pop up each time, but it's become a minor annoyance.

I tried "npm cache clean --force" but the problem persists.

Please help me find a way to get rid of these undefined packages forever, thank you for your time!

Comment: Since this `npm list -g --depth 0` show these at top level. How about trying `npm -g uninstall react@npm:undefined@0.1.0 --save` and the other one.

Comment: @ambianBeing Of course I tried that, the two undefined packages get uninstalled alright, only to get installed automatically again with the next "npm update -g".

Comment: Ok! That's wierd that even after uninstalling globally they show up. Another thing that can be tried is to check the root of npm installation by `npm -g root` (in ubuntu its `usr/lib/node_modules`) and delete their respective folders from there.

Comment: @ambianBeing I can confirm that deleting the folders of the undefined packages from npm's root folder fixed my problem. They aren't getting auto re-added anymore when I run "npm update -g", thank you!

Comment: Great! That it solved the issue. May i suggest you post that as an answer to the question, if it is something future readers might find helpful. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved after I manually deleted the folders of the undefined projects from the root of my npm installation, on the advice of @ambianBeing.

Note: you can locate the root of your npm installation with `npm -g root`.